# Однокоренные слова - "убрала", "взобралась", "собрались"

Tags: морфемика

"Убрала", "взобралась", "собрались".  Все ли слова в этом ряду являются однокоренными?

Answer (score 1):

**СОБРАТЬСЯ**

Происходит от собрать, из со- + брать, далее от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. берѫ, бьрати, русск. беру, брать, укр. беру́, бра́ти, болг. бера́, сербохорв. бе̏ре̑м, бра̏ти, словенск. bérem, bráti, чешск. beru, brát, польск. biorę, brać, в.-луж. bjeru, brać, н.-луж. bjeru, braś. Древнее знач. сохранилось в слове бере́мя. Исконнородственны др.-инд. bhárati, bíbharti, bibhárti «несет, приносит, ведет, отнимает», авест. baraiti «несет», греч. φέρω «несу», арм. berem — то же, алб. bie «веду, приношу», лат. fero «несу», готск. baíra «несу», ирл. biru «несу» (в соединении с to- «приношу, даю»). Возм., сюда же лит. beriù, bėriaũ, ber̃ti «сыпать», латышск. beŕu, bẽrt «сыпать». Другая ступень чередования представлена в др.-инд. bhṛtíṣ «несение, содержание, вознаграждение», лат. fors «случай», ирл. brith «рождение», готск. baurþei, нем. Bürde «ноша», Geburt «рождение»; ст.-слав. бьранъ, прич. прош. страд.: др.-инд. bibhrāṇas и др. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Короче, "брать" можно в разных направлениях. И все эти слова, на мой взгляд, действительно однокоренные.

Answer (score 0):

Исторически - да.
Сейчас, конечно, значения порядком разошлись, школьникам, наверное, о древних корнях не сообщают.